# Как поменять фон в Navigation Drawer с помощью кнопки в фрагменте

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-navigation-drawer, android-navigation-view

Имеется Navigation Drawer в нем  пару фрагментов и в одно из них есть кнопка которая должна изменить фон в менюшке Navigation Drawer. Я даже не могу получить id layout что бы изменить его фон.
Вот код метода:

```
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_activity3, container, false);


    Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Layout asas = (Layout) getView().findViewById(R.layout.nav_header_navigation);



    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            asas.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu1);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

[image: вот это менюшка]

Comment: Во первых так у вас не получится, т.к. Левое меню в активити а вы в разметке фрагмента ищете. Во вторых у вас явно какая-то сторонняя либа заюзана для меню, но вы это даже не упомянули.

Comment: Да это не моя картинка, и я смог сделать в  классе Navigation Drawer метод который изменяет картинку. Но я не как не могу вызвать его через фрагмент пишет что нужно статический метод и при изменения на статический в методе есть объявление разметки с фрагментом он пишет что findViewById не работает.

Comment: Вы так и не ответили используете ли вы стороннюю либу для дровера. Пока вы не ответите - помочь вам нельзя. И повторю - в разметке фрагмента нет дровера и нет смысла пытаться там его искать

Comment: Библиотека стандартная

Comment: То есть стороннего нету не чего, с шаблона взял

Comment: Тогда вам надо как-то так: `View header = ((NavigationView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.navigationDrawer)).getHeaderView(0); header.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);`

Comment: Естесственно этот код дословно у вас не скомпилируется. Вам надо подставить нужные ID.